# What's wrong with my Custom Report Type

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I am trying to get a report of X-without-Y type kind of report.

So I [created a Formula field](https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HZubEAG) (Number,0) with value of '1' for every Object  (Account, Contact, Oppty, etc )

[image]

I than created a Custom Report type

[image]

Created a report using the custom report type, and added a filter to display all Accounts where Contact is not equal to 1

[image]

ALAS: The report returns accounts that DO have records, even that these do NOT show on the report itself

- In the following example: Company : no - has no shown contacts

[image]

- when looking on the 'no' object - there is a contact

[image]

- What an I missing?
- This happens both with Account <> Contacts, Account <> Opportuinties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You selected Accounts WITH or WITHOUT Contacts, therefore, the report is going to ignore your filter criteria and will pull records that "apparently" don't match.  You can create this type of reports using cross filters

[image]